# How to pass data to eth_sendTransaction?

Tags: solidity, ethers.js

I'm calling the function "`confirmVote(NUMBER)`" from my contract.

In this contract I do not have the "`fallcack`" or "`receive`" functions, as the contract does not receive a token (`ETH`), users only pay a gas fee.

However, it is giving an error in the transaction, most likely it is because the data is empty.

From what I understand, I must pass my function called as data, how do I do this?

```
const CONTRACT_SIGNER = PROVIDER_CONTRACT.web3.connect(useEthers.states.provider.web3.getSigner());
    
const ESTIMAGE_GAS = await CONTRACT_SIGNER.estimateGas.confirmVote(candidateID);
    
await window.ethereum.request({
    method: 'eth_sendTransaction',
    params: [
        {
            data: ????,
            from: '',
            to: '',
            gas: '',
            value: 0,
        },
    ],
});
    
const TRANSACTION_RECEIPT = await WEB3_PROVIDER.waitForTransaction(TRANSACTION as string);

if (TRANSACTION_RECEIPT.status === 1) {
    await CONTRACT_SIGNER.confirmVote(candidateID)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `CONTRACT_SIGNER` is an ethers contract instance you can get the encoded data for a function call as follows

`const data = CONTRACT_SIGNER.interface.encodeFunctionData('confirmVote', [5])`

Usually you dont have to do this as it is abstracted away in the ethers contract instance - to perform the `confirmVote(uint)` transaction you only need the line

`await CONTRACT_SIGNER.confirmVote(candidateID)`